# Ways for lazy "run once" initialization in Java with override from unit tests

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, lazy-evaluation

I'm looking for a piece of code which behaves a bit like a singleton but isn't (because singleton's are bad :) What I'm looking for must meet these goals:

1. Thread safe
2. Simple (Understand & use, i.e. few lines of code. Library calls are OK)
3. Fast
4. Not a singleton; for tests, it must be possible to overwrite the value (and reset it after the test).
5. Local (all necessary information must be in one place)
6. Lazy (run only when the value is actually needed).
7. Run once (code on RHS must be executed once and only once)

Example code:

```
private int i = runOnce(5); // Set i to 5
// Create the connection once and cache the result
private Connection db = runOnce(createDBConnection("DB_NAME"));

public void m() {
    String greet = runOnce("World");
    System.out.println("Hello, "+greet+"!");
}
```

Note that the fields are *not* static; only the RHS (right hand side) of the expression is ... well "static" to some degree. A test should be able to inject new values for `i` and `greet` temporarily.

Also note that this piece of code outlines how I intend to use this new code. Feel free to replace runOnce() with anything or move it to some other place (the constructor, maybe, or an init() method or a getter). But the less LOC, the better.

Some background information:

I'm not looking for Spring, I'm looking for a piece of code which can be used for the most common case: You need to implement an interface and there won't ever be a second implementation except for tests where you want to pass in mock objects. Also, Spring fails #2, #3 and #5: You need to learn the config language, you must set up the app context somewhere, it needs an XML parser and it's not local (information is spread all over the place).

A global config object or factory doesn't meet the bill because of #5.

`static final` is out because of #4 (can't change final). `static` smells because of classloader issues but you'll probably need it inside `runOnce()`. I'd just prefer to be able to avoid it in the LHS of the expression.

One possible solution might be to use [ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/) with a default setup which would return the same object. Since I can put things in the cache, this would also allow to override the value at any time. But maybe there is a more compact/simple solution than ehcache (which again needs an XML config file, etc).

[EDIT] I'm wondering why so many people downvote this. It's a valid question and the use case is pretty common (at least in my code). So if you don't understand the question (or the reason behind it) or if you have no answer or you don't care, why downvote? :/

[EDIT2] If you look at the app context of Spring, you'll find that more than 99% of all beans have just a single implementation. You could have more but in practice, you simply don't. So instead of separating interface, implementation and configuration, I'm looking at something which has only an implementation (in the most simple case), a current() method and one or two lines of clever code to initialize the result for current() once (when it is called for the first time) but at the same times allows to override the result (thread safe, if possible). Think of it as an atomic "if(o==null) o = new O(); return o" where you can override the o. Maybe an AtomicRunOnceReference class is the solution.

Right now, I just feel that what we all have and use daily is not the optimum, that there is a baffling solution which will make us all slap our heads and say "that's it". Just as we felt when Spring came around a few years ago and we realized where all our singleton problems came from and how to solve them.

Comment: From your “requirements” I haven’t been able to gather what you are actually looking for. Can you explain?

Comment: I'm looking for a simple way to evaluate an expression once, cache the result and being able to override this result from a unit test.

Comment: You can't post a list of 7 requirements like you did, and expect an answer which will fully satisfy all of them.

Comment: Yuval: I feel that this is a pretty common issue in Java and I was wondering if someone had a better solution than Spring or static final. So what's wrong with posting my requirements?

Comment: I'm thinking about turning this into a community wiki to collect all the (correct) ways how to lazy init a variable + pro/cons. Comments?

Comment: Aaron: turning in to CW seems like a good idea to get the best answer within the limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that fulfills all my requirements:

```
/** Lazy initialization of a field value based on the (correct)
* double checked locking idiom by Joschua Bloch
*
* <p>See "Effective Java, Second Edition", p. 283
*/
public abstract class LazyInit<T>
{
    private volatile T field;

    /** Return the value.
    *
    *  <p>If the value is still <code>null</code>, the method will block and
    *  invoke <code>computeValue()</code>. Calls from other threads will wait
    *  until the call from the first thread will complete.
    */
    @edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings("UG_SYNC_SET_UNSYNC_GET")
    public T get ()
    {
        T result = field;
        if (result == null) // First check (no locking)
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                result = field;
                if (result == null) // Second check (with locking)
                {
                    field = result = computeValue ();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected abstract T computeValue ();

    /** Setter for tests */
    public synchronized void set (T value)
    {
        field = value;
    }

    public boolean hasValue()
    {
        return field != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you alter the value?  You need to make sure no thread is accessing, so all threads are finished. Thus, having `synchronized set`  helps not, the solution is **not thread safe**, if any thread is still using 'field'.

Comment: @bestsss: This is not correct; the field is volatile and changing a single field is atomic in Java, so the setter is thread safe. It should even be thread safe without the "synchronized" keyword. In fact, I just checked with `AtomicReference` and removed the "synchronized".

Comment: @bestsss: Also keep in mind that in the usual case, no one calls the setter - it exists so test cases can overwrite the singleton.

Comment: AtomicReference is just a volatile w/ CAS enabled. I am not talking about the assignment which would be thread safe either way but about the use of the assigned object. Again: if a thread is still using the old object, there will be a data race once set is' called. Now the code explicitly relies that by the time `set` is called, no object creation is in process (you have a true data race there) and the 'old' object is not being used any more. Synchronized on set was good at least to prevent not setting during computeValue().

Comment: Imagine a computeValue() is in progress and a call to set is performed? Whoever finishes last overwrites the previous value unconditionally. Meantime the result of computeValue() would be used by some thread while 'field' contains some other reference. Your best bet would be to use generation w/ version check and ThreadLocals to achieve the goal. You just cannot reset a value still being in use.

Comment: *Also keep in mind that in the usual case, no one calls the setter - it exists so test cases can overwrite the singleton*, that means that the test case has to be able to ensure ALL the threads have finished (mostly cooperatively and using a ThreadGroup, so the threads can be monitored). If a test fails, no further tests can progress. In such cases, I'd recommend loading the tests into a separate classloader to prevent any stale static date/state between the tests, not only the singleton.

Comment: @bestsss: The synchronized would make sure that computeValue() and set() are properly executed one after the other. I thought more than I remember when I wrote this :-) As for threads: The behavior is correct. If a thread uses `get()`, it will always get the current value. If that is bad, the thread has to cache the value. If it caches the value, it needs to make sure the cache is refreshed properly. There is no way to tell outside of the thread how this should happen and when. But since each thread has control when and how it accesses the value, you can always find a correct solution.

Comment: I reverted my edit. The synchronized is correct. There is no need to monitor threads or any such magic since each thread can fetch the value as is necessary and correct in the context of the problem the thread needs to solve.

Answer (score 6):

The best idiom for threadsafe initialization code (imho) is the lazy inner class.  The classic version is

```
class Outer {
  class Inner {
    private final static SomeInterface SINGLETON;

    static {
      // create the SINGLETON
    }
  }

  public SomeInterface getMyObject() {
    return Inner.SINGLETON;
  }
}
```

because it's threadsafe, lazy-loading and (imho) elegant.

Now you want testability and replaceability.  It's hard to advise without knowing what exactly it is but the most obvious solution would be to use dependency injection, particularly if you're using Spring and have an application context anyway.

That way your "singleton"'s behaviour is represented by an interface and you simply inject one of those  into your relevant classes (or a factory to produce one) and then you can of course replace it with whatever you like for testing purposes.

Comment: Actually the third paragraph addresses testabbility.  Just how spoonfed do you want to be exactly?  And you downvote for that?

Comment: I already said that Spring is not an option. I don't want to be spoonfed; I've seen about a dozen different ways for lazy init+override which all have their drawbacks. All I'm looking for is whether someone has a better solution than Spring/Guice/etc.

Comment: I downvote because the answer doesn't fit to my question but if you feel so bad about it, I can undo it, no prob. No stress, OK?

Comment: the compilation of the inner class and the time to get properly JITted + the extra memory it takes doesn't make it look elegant, imo. The volatile read will probably outweight it performance wise. Also failing to create the singleton once means it will never be created... you have 2 options keep: it null or ExceptionInInitializerError + NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IoC techniques even if you dont use an IoC framework (Spring/Guice/...). And it is in my opinion the only clean way to avoid a Singleton.

Comment: Sounds promising. Do you have an idea how a distributed IoC container would look like? An IoC container is basically a synchronized map. How would you move all the necessary logic into a few lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution you could use is providing a protected method which can be overriden in the test (a solution I've used before for testing legacy code).

So something like:

```
private SomeObject object;

protected SomeObject getObject() {
   if (object == null) {
       object = new SomeObject();
   }
   return object;
}
```

Then in your test class you can do:

```
public void setUp() {
   MyClassUnderTest cut = new MyClassUserTest() {
      @Override
      protected SomeObject getObject() }
         return mockSomeObject;
      }
   };
}
```

I have to say I'm not overly keen on this pattern as it exposes the protected field where you might not really want it, but it's useful for getting you out of some situations where injection isn't an option

Comment: -1, Does not fit "run once" (new #7, formerly only in the description). I want to avoid calling the code in "new SomeObject()" repeatedly because it is expensive.

Comment: Now does lazy initialization.